# Save files behind root - Codeigniter

Tags: file, codeigniter

I want to save files on the server, but I want to add these files behind the root.

How do I set my path so it is pointed behind my root directory?

realpath (APPPATH) gives me this: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webites/Sitename/public_html/application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gee the full root path starting with a slash:

"/myfiles/go/here/"